How to test the websocket connection in django channels
I need to test the success of the websocket connection. When connecting, the query_string parameter is checked. If it is transmitted, the connection is allowed. If not, the connection is closed.
At the moment, the test fails with an error:
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<ProtocolTypeRouter.__call__() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/routing.py:62> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object ProtocolTypeRouter.__call__ at 0xffff845ac3c0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 62, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 41, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 55, in await_many_dispatch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 753, in call_soon
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<Queue.get() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/queues.py:159> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<InMemoryChannelLayer.receive() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/layers.py:249> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object InMemoryChannelLayer.receive at 0xffff845ac7b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/layers.py", line 249, in receive
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/queues.py", line 161, in get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 753, in call_soon
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed


My application configuration:
settings.py
ASGI_APPLICATION = "hs_cubic.asgi.application"
ASGI_MAX_WORKER_RUNTIME = 60 * 10
ASGI_WORKERS = 4
ASGI_THREADS = 4
ASGI_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10000
ASGI_MAX_REDIRECTS = 5
ASGI_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT = 60
ASGI_KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL = 60
ASGI_MAX_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION = 1000
ASGI_GRACEFUL_TIMEOUT = 60
ASGI_RELOAD = True
ASGI_BACKEND = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
ASGI_REDIS_URL = os.getenv("REDIS_LOCATION")

asgi.py
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

websocket_urlpatterns = []
websocket_urlpatterns.extend(auth_routers)

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns)
        ),
        'http': django_asgi_app
    }
)

pytest.ini
[pytest]
asyncio_mode = auto
pythonpath = hs_cubic/
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = hs_cubic.settings
norecursedirs = env/*
addopts = -vv -p no:cacheprovider
; addopts = -vv -p no:cacheprovider -p no:warnings
testpaths = tests/
python_files = test_*.py

test.py
from channels.testing import WebsocketCommunicator, ApplicationCommunicator
from hs_cubic.asgi import application

TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}


@pytest.mark.asyncio(loop_scope="class")
class TestWebsocketConnection:
    loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop

    async def test_successful_connection_websocket(self, settings):
        session_id = "test_session_id"
        channel_name = "test_channel_name"
        data = {"test": "message"}
        settings.CHANNEL_LAYERS = TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS

        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(application, f"ws/telegram_auth/?session_id={session_id}")
        connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
        assert connected is True
        await communicator.disconnect()

conftest.py is empty
